# display and order posts like on facebook

Tags: php, mysql, post

I'm having an issues with my queried results. I have three tables, a follower table, a user table, and a posts table, while my logged in user = $user_name. My code calls all from follower table where the the follower is = to the logged in user, and calls the name of all the users their following ($followi). Then I call all from the posts table where the posters name is = to the username of the users the user is following. and the code works.

MY PROBLEM: I have tried to order my results by date, but MYSQL is placing precedence on the Followi, and displays in order of user who posted, then order of date. so if one user has 2 posts a month apart, it displays these two, then displays the next user, even if they posted 5 times in the last minute.

how do i display ONLY Based on date while keeping it to where it only displays the posts of users that the logged user is following?

heres my code

```
 <?php

$follow = "SELECT followi from follow where follower = '$user_name'";
$runf = mysqli_query($con,$follow);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($runf)){
$followi = $row['followi'];


$sel_msg = "SELECT * from posts where poster_name = '$followi' ORDER by post_time desc";
$run_msg = mysqli_query($con,$sel_msg);

while($row_msg=mysqli_fetch_array($run_msg)){



echo "
<div id='post_box'>
".$row_msg['post_content']."
</div>
"; 
}}
?>
```

Comment: @dharman which part of my code is open to injection? I thought injection could only be run when users post content

Comment: `'$user_name'` and `'$followi'`. You should put placeholders and parameterize the values. Injection occurs when you put variables in the SQL. You should never do that, even if the variables do not come from user input.

Comment: @dharman huge thanks brother, i'll work on trying to get that fixed on my site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your loop starts with the followersi data (the while loop). This is the order you are retrieving data and displaying it in the current logic:

Get posts for User A

- User A Post 1
- User A Post 2
- User A Post 3

Get posts for User B

- User B Post 1
- User B Post 2
- User B Post 3

What I believe you are trying to do is get the posts in date order but retrieve the user information to display at the same time. You can do that with a JOIN statement e.g.

```
$sel_msg = "SELECT posts.*, users.name, users.image 
            FROM posts
            JOIN users ON posts.userId = users.id
            ORDER BY post_time DESC";

$run_msg = mysqli_query($con,$sel_msg);
```

There is no need for the first sql statement in your code

Comment: awesome huge thanks! when i have enough reputation, i'll deffinatly up vote you